# Installing SaltStack on RHEL 7?

Tags: salt-stack, rhel7

I need help on installing saltstack on RHEL 7.

RHEL 7 server is from AWS Amazon.

$ cat /etc/redhat-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

I'm getting an error during installation:

$ wget -O - http://bootstrap.saltstack.org | sudo sh

2014-08-04 09:41:45 (932 KB/s) - written to stdout [177548/177548]

- INFO: Found function install_red_hat_enterprise_linux_7_stable_deps
- INFO: Found function install_red_hat_enterprise_linux_stable
- INFO: Found function install_red_hat_enterprise_linux_stable_post
- INFO: Found function install_red_hat_enterprise_linux_restart_daemons
- INFO: Found function daemons_running
- INFO: Running install_red_hat_enterprise_linux_7_stable_deps()
- **ERROR**: Stable version is not available on RHEL 7 Beta/RC. Please set installation type to git.
- **ERROR**: Failed to run install_red_hat_enterprise_linux_7_stable_deps()!!!

Is this version of RHEL 7 not supported for saltstack?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands to install from the latest develop branch:

```
curl -o install_salt.sh -L https://bootstrap.saltstack.com
sudo sh install_salt.sh -M git develop
```

Remove the `-M` from the command above if you don't want to install a salt-master and only want to install salt-minion.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, I tried to install it from epel 7 beta, but there's another problem, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1127348. Finally I was able to install it by combining pip and yum. I don't have the exact sequence of commands, but sth. like this should work:

```
yum install --skip-broken salt python-pip
pip install jinja2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried installing SaltStack on CentOS 7 , which should be similar to Redhat 7, and you could try it, hope it works for you:

```
**[updated]** http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm
```

and then you could

```
yum install -y salt-master
```

or

```
yum install -y install salt-minion
```

to install it.

Comment: This url doesn't exist. http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: The most generic way to enable the EPEL repositories (and this applies to RHEL 6 and 7) is to simply `yum install epel-release` as the package is in the core RHEL repositories. No more worrying about version-release conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the rhel-7-server-optional-rpms repo in subscription-manager.